# How to set the insets of a JViewport

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm aware of `setViewportBorder()`, however I'm wondering if you can set the bounds of the viewport rather than just padding with an empty border. What I'd like to achieve is create room for a header and footer component inline with the increase and decrease buttons.

```
                  _
                 |^|
 ----------------| |
|                | |
|   JViewport    | |
|________________| |
                 |v|
```

Comment: tweak the scrollPane's LayoutManager to accept additional component/s

Comment: JViewport covers whole JScrollPanes Rectangle, you can to put XxxBorders to the JViewport, but with side effects

Comment: btw: Jide commons has scrollPane/Layout with additional components - you might want to look into its code to get some ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could always roll-your-own

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class Testing
{
  public void buildGUI()
  {
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10,10);
    ta.setLineWrap(true);
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ta,ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,
                                      ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    JLabel header = new JLabel("Header",JLabel.CENTER);
    JLabel footer = new JLabel("Footer",JLabel.CENTER);
    JScrollBar sBar = new JScrollBar();
    sp.getVerticalScrollBar().setModel(sBar.getModel());
    p.add(header,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    p.add(sp,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    p.add(footer,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    for(int x = 0; x < 50; x++) ta.append(x+"\n");
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.getContentPane().add(p);
    f.getContentPane().add(sBar,BorderLayout.EAST);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
        new Testing().buildGUI();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked very well, I've never used `setModel`. The only addition I had to make was to add a `mouseWheelListener` to the content of the viewport. Thanks